# Kafka producer: NoBrokersAvailable in docker

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-producer-api

I'm starting with kafka and my project consists in get data and put it into a kafka topic.

I was trying to do it without docker, **executing the data-generator in an python environment and it works perfectly**, but in docker not.

My docker-compose is the following code:

```sh
version: '3.8'
services:

  data-generator:
    build: ./data-generator
    container_name: data-generator
    depends_on:
      - kafka

  zkpr:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.3
    container_name: zkpr
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    healthcheck: { test: nc -z localhost 2181, interval: 1s, start_period: 120s }
  
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.5.3
    depends_on: [zkpr]
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zkpr:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    ports:
    - 9092:9092
    - 9094:9094
    healthcheck: { test: nc -z localhost 9092, interval: 1s, start_period: 120s }


  materialized:
    image: materialize/materialized:v0.20.0
    container_name: materialized
    command: -w1
    ports:
      - 6875:6875

  mzcli:
    image: materialize/cli
    container_name: mzcli
    depends_on:
      - materialized

  dbt:
    build:
      context: ./dbt
      target: dbt-third-party
      args:
        - build_for=${ARCH}
    container_name: dbt
    ports:
      - 8000:8080
    volumes:
      - ./dbt/profiles.yml:/root/.dbt/profiles.yml
      - ./dbt/:/usr/app/dbt
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - materialized

  metabase:
    image: ${MIMG}/metabase
    container_name: metabase
    depends_on:
       - materialized
    ports:
      - 3030:3000
```

The producer that i'm using is a python code with the following code:

```sh
    # Producer instance
    prod = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092')

    try:

        urlData = "url"

        jsonData = getResponse(urlData)

        for i in jsonData["resources"]:
            
            ## code

            prod.send(topic='topic', key=i["key"].encode('utf-8'), value=json_value.encode('utf-8'))

        prod.flush()

        #code

    except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: %s" % str(e),file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

    # code
```

The problem occurs when connecting the producer to the kafka, maybe the ports, or the ip, there are no problems getting the data or processing it.

If someone knows how to solve the problem i would be really grateful.

Comment: Does your script wait for Kafka to be ready?

Comment: Note: `depends_on` doesnt wait for the Kafka server healthcheck to start